# Notice: Undefined index: chk_name only when using checkbox and radiobutton when posting form in bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using twitter bootstrap modal dialog to edit records but when i post my form by clicking on a submit button i get all values on the next page except radio buttons and check boxes values i have searched every where on the net but did not get any solution for that. Please help to solve that. Thanks in advance.... Below is my code....

```
<div class="modal-body">
<form role="form" class="form-horizontal" name="edit_user_info" id="edit_user_info" method="post" action="dbinsert.php">
<input type="hidden" name="Op" value="EditUser" />
<input name="user_id" type="hidden" value="<?=$row['user_id'];?>" />
<fieldset>
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="focusedInput">Name</label>
<div class="controls">
<input class="input-xlarge focused" id="txtName" name="txtName" type="text" value="<?=$row['name']?>"/>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label">Notify</label>
<div class="controls">
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="radioNotify" style="padding-left: 0px;" value='0' <?php echo ($row['Notify']== '0') ?  "checked" : "" ;  ?> /> Enable 
</label>
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="radioNotify" value='1' <?php echo ($row['Notify']== '1') ?  "checked" : "" ;  ?> /> Disable
</label>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="opt_block_User">Included Fare</label>
<div class="controls">
<label class="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkinclude_fare" value="1" <?php echo $row["Fare"] ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?> />
Check and Uncheck
</label>
</div>
</div>
</fieldset>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
<input name="button1" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
</div>
```

dbinsert.php

```
if( isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST) ){
    $type = $_POST['Op'];
    switch($type){
        case 'EditUser': EditUser();
            break;    

}
}

function EditUser()
{
$id=$_POST['user_id'];
$name=$_POST['txtName'];
echo "name...".$name;
echo "id...".$id;
echo "Block...".$_POST['chk_block'];
echo "Notify....".$_POST['radioNotify'];
}
```

I am getting id value and name value but not radio button and checkbox value.

Comment: Does this only happen when you haven't checked the checkbox/radio button?

Comment: No despite of checking it it shows undefined index